# Are other ways of neutrinos being "destroyed"?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos

I understand that neutrinos are absorbed and such, but are there any other way for neutrinos to be "destroyed" per se?

Comment: Since you say 'absorbed and such' and then ask for other ways, it is unclear what you are asking. Do you consider undergoing a nuclear reaction to be 'absorbed' for example? Or is that under the 'and such'?

Comment: I apologize for being unclear. When I stated that neutrinos are being absorbed  I meant all ways of being absorbed. I'm more interested in other ways of neutrinos being destroyed such as annihilation of a neutrino and anti neutrino.

Answer (score 1):

Neutrinos interact via the weak force, and we describe these interactions by the exchange of $W$ and $Z$ bosons. So in addition to $\nu\bar\nu$ annihilation neutrinos can be created and destroyed by weak interactions. Note however that lepton number is always conserved so typically it will disappear by transforming into another lepton. For example:

[image: Neutrino absorption]

In this process a neutrino scatters off a neutron and disappears by turning into an electron.